# How can I transform input stream when I'm using stax2 XMLInputFactory2?

Tags: java, stax, woodstox

Parsing big xml files (500 - 800Mb) using stax2 like that:

```
XMLStreamReader2 reader = (XMLStreamReader2) xmlif2.createXMLStreamReader(fileName, new FileInputStream(fileName));
```

to convert it into specific csv and have a next problem. Some text nodes contains "&#x1;" sequence. In output file it have to be replaced with cyrillic letter "Ё". But when parser found that sequence "&#x1;", it's throw exception:

> [com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxLazyException]
>   com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Illegal character entity:
>   expansion character (code 0x1  at [row,col,system-id]

In stax I have same exception.

Can I set some transforation for xml stream reader and replace &#x1; to Ё automative while parsing???
I can create intermediate file, where all be replaced, and than parse it, but it's not good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error message indicates that your XML is not well-formed: either its encoding is broken.
It sounds like it contains an entity reference for Unicode character with value 0x1.
This is not allowed for XML 1.0; although it would be legal for XML 1.1.
But perhaps XML document does not declare "version='1.0'" in its xml declaration?

Comment: Xml files have a next header
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>`

If changing of xml version resolve trouble it would be better to do that before parsing than replace all &#x1; sequences

Comment: Right, XML 1.0 does not allow character entities to refer to control characters (0x1 - 0x1F, except for lf/cr/tab). So try changing 1.0 to 1.1 and problem should be avoided.